# STM32F767ZI interface with DAC082S085

Tags: arm, keil, dac, stm32f7, cubemx

I plan to use STM32F767ZI USART port in synchronous mode and control DAC (DAC082S085) for generating two Analog Signals. I also want to control the amplitude of these analog signals. So, how can I do in CubeMx and Keil?

Thank you

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: Actually, I switched my approach. I will use SPI instead of USART. But I have a still problem 16 bit defining. For example, in Keil, HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi6, uint16_t *)Data, 16, 100) function has error. The error is uint16_t is incompatible. I will just only send data as MOSI to DAC.